# Open specific ViewController but with the correct 'view-path' when a notification comes in

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, remote-notifications

So i know how to open a specific ViewController (aktuellesTVC) when a remote push notification comes in. But it just opens that view without the 'path'.

With the path, i mean all the views that i would open first to come to that view without a notification.

As example:
SplitViewController -> Navigation Controller -> mainMenuVC -> Navigation Controller -> aktuellesTVC
(the path to my view i want to open when i tap a notification)

I need that path, so that if I open the view with the notification i want to be able to go back to the mainMenuVC and continue using my app. Basically i think WhatsApp does this too, when you touch a notification it opens the chat directly but after you can go back to the all-chats-view.

Comment: There is no direct api for it if this is what you are looking for. You will have to write your code to create desired path for ex: Open VC1 and trigger VC2 segue within VC1 and so on. You can choose to switch animation OFF for opening parent VCs and keep animation ON for final VC.

Comment: Simply use pushViewController(_:animated:), with animated set to false - this way everything will be fine in the VC hierarchy.

Comment: Worked nice! I save a string to NSUserDefaults and 'restart' the app, then every VC to the final makes a segue when this UserDefault is set and the final VC sets it back to nil. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Swift Navigate to certain ViewController programmatically from push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058261/ios-swift-navigate-to-certain-viewcontroller-programmatically-from-push-notifica)